# top of scrollable text is cut off

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with storyboards and have put text inside a table cell within a ViewController. The text shows up correctly in portrait view without need for set constraints. However, on landscape view without constraints the text does not fill the entire width. Thus, I apply constraints to fill the canvas with text but the top part of the text does not appear.

I have this hierarchy:

- View Controller

  - Table View

    - Table View Section
    - Table View Cell

      - Content View
      - Label
      - Constraints

(Constraints are set for vertical top, and both horizontal sides)
I have autolayout checked, working with attributed text, word wrap, with about 30 lines and indent head at 20. Without an indent the clipping or cutting off does not occur, but it makes my text start about midway on the screen as opposed to just below the navigation bar.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Attached Link https://www.flickr.com/photos/115284261@N02/sets/72157640082717193/

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your storyboard layout and the issue in the simulator?

Comment: I tried, sorry but this is the first time I use this site and it doesn't allow me to post images until I reach a reputation of 10.

Comment: you said that without _indentation_ the text starts _midway on the screen_. Did you mean "_midway on screen, but still just below navigation bar_" ?

Comment: I've uploaded the images to flickr to make this easier to explain. https://www.flickr.com/photos/115284261@N02/sets/72157640082717193/ When I don't use indentation for the text it displays all the text but it starts midway on screen, still showing the navigation bar. Hope this makes it more clear. Thank you.